# Question about absolute value, if I can rewrite something in an absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

I have one simple question.

If we have $\displaystyle(x^4)^\frac{1}{2}$, Can I rewrite it as this $\displaystyle |x^2|$?

I am awared that I can rewrite $\displaystyle (x^2)^\frac{1}{2} as\;|x|$ so it is most probably true. :D

thx

Comment: Yes you can write it also $|x^{2}|=x^{2}$ because it's always positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And you can write it as $x^2$ too, since $x^2=\lvert x^2\rvert(=\lvert x\rvert^2)$.